# Bootstrap 4 navbar collapse .show class delay after .collapsing disable

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the bootstrap 4 collapse, i need to disable the delay in `.show` class that appears after `.collapsing` class.

So what I need is to show `.show` class on `.collapse` class immediately after clicking the `toggle`.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to prevent the `.collapsing` class from being applied to the .collapse element so there's always going to be a delay. Instead of Collapse you could use jQuery to toggle display of the Navbar...

```
$('[data-toggle=display]').on('click', function() {
    var target = $($(this).data("target"));
    target.toggleClass("d-none d-block");
})
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/nFbagrqHWa

---

**EDIT**

Here's how the Collapse component works...

- `.collapse` hides the content
- `.collapsing` is *applied* when the transition starts (the `show.bs.collapse` event is fired)
- `.collapsing` is *removed*, and `.collapse.show` is applied when the transition end (the `shown.bs.collapse` event is fired)

The reverse happens when the element is triggered again and the `hide.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events are fired.

The `show.bs.collapse` event is fired when the `.collapsing` class is applied. You could add a handler for the `show.bs.collapse` event to add the `.show` class *when* the `.collapsing` class is applied. However, that's ***not*** going to effect the transition animation and there will still be a delay.

Add `.show` when `.collapsing` is applied..

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).addClass("show");
});
```

And, optionally remove it on the 'hide' event.

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).addClass("show");
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).removeClass("show");
}).
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/YBXzYG8fgy

Or, override the transistion with CSS:

```
#navbarNav {transition: none;}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/zCAqhDVnDW

Comment: i don't want the `.collapsing` class to not being applied. instead, i wanted to trigger `.show` class immediately without delay

Comment: Do you really think my answer deserves a downvote? Perhaps you should clarify the question and explain what you trying to accomplish and **why** you want to apply the `show` class during `collapsing`.

Comment: again, you are still not clear with my question. perhaps you didn't read the description very well or you didn't check the code snippet. this `.show` class appears on bootstrap 4 collapse but after `.collapsing` class. if you inspect the element and take a look, you'll notice `.show` class is delayed. that's where i need help. i need this `.show` to trigger immediately with `.collapsing` class. let me know if you are still not clear

Comment: I have already answered the question and explained how to add the `show` class immediately after clicking the toggle. Did you read the answer?

Comment: thanks, that helped. and please remember to remind about the edited answer :)